# Can I remove diagnostics.wadcfg safely now we have diagnostics.wadcfgx?

Tags: wcf, azure, diagnostics

I have an WCF service on Azure with diagnostics/logging enabled. The project is already existing for some time and transitted through Visual Studio 2012, 2013 and now 2015. I discovered there is two diagnostics.wadcfg(X) files.

- Can I remove diagnostics.wadcfg?
- Where I can find some information on .wadcfg and .wadcfgx? Meaning what Microsoft Tooling was upgraded at some point in time that we now need .wadcfgx?

Thanks. BR, Rene

Answer (score 0):

wadcfg can be safely removed and so is the reference to Azure Diagnostics -- assuming you've upgraded to Azure SDK 2.5+